# My Droid did a system update and erased everything

Tags: updates, restore

My Droid Incredible did a system update & went to factory reset. Everything is gone.
Can I go back and restore?

Comment: although, I still have my wallpaper & my ringtones

Answer (score 0):

Unless you had a back-up, it would be impossible to go back to a previous state. However, if you enabled Google sync, you can still restore your contacts, calendar, and other Google-syncable data.

After a Factory Reset, you will be asked to log-in to your Google account again. After which, it may ask you if you want to re-install some apps that you paid for previously. It will not install the free apps; you may want to install them manually.

Comment: @KarenMKonczyk It has happened to me a lot of times in the past too. I don't use a lockscreen, so it's quite easy to trigger a Factory Reset when I've got my phone and my hands inside my pocket.

Comment: It read that it needed to do a system update. It does often. This is the first for this..

Comment: Can you help with this????? I signed into my google acct. When I hit internet , it reads process.android.browser has stopped unexpectedly ..Please try again. Make me hit force close. I can't get on the internet

Comment: @KarenMKonczyk Can you turn it off, and try again?

Comment: tried that...I've been clearing data on all apps & still can't get on the internet. DO i really have to do a factory reset?

Comment: Support Internet browser keeps "stopping unexpectedly".  Process android.browser   Help